# How do I get my videos to work in my website?

Tags: php, html

The videos on the website just show as a static image.You can not interact, pause, full screen or anything.

//this loop is just selecting the video and pulling it out of the files and displaying it.

```
        <video>
            <source src="Pics/animations/'.$row2["imgFullNameAnimations"].'" type=video/'.$row2["endingAnimations"].'>
        </video>
```

Comment: I haven't worked with the video tag, but it looks like you forgot `"` after `type=`?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo in your example but ```</video``` should be ```</video>```

Comment: Bad copy paste sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you see a static image but what you are seeing is the start of your video. You need to either add the `autoplay` attribute and/or the `controls` attribute. The first one will auto start your video while the `controls` will give you the option to start, skip, full screen.

```
<video controls>
        <source src="Pics/animations/'.$row2["imgFullNameAnimations"].'" type=video/'.$row2["endingAnimations"].'>
     </video>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_controls.asp